# How can I automount an external harddrive if and only if it's connected to the computer as it boots?

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, mount

I have an eSATA harddrive connected to my laptop's dock.  Unfortunately it doesn't automatically mount when Ubuntu boots, nor is editing fstab an option, given that the harddrive is not *always* present when the computer boots.  When the disk is absent, Ubuntu will complain.

Is there a way to mount the disk if it's present at boot-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can safely add your drive to fstab, I think there's an option for partitions that are not always present, possibly 'nofail', though that has been known to cause problems, like read-only file-system, so [proceed cautiously](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=67814#p386448)

More information:

```
   The  mountall(8)  program  that  mounts  filesystem  during  boot  also
   recognises additional options that the ordinary mount(8) tool does not.
   These  are:  ``bootwait''  which  can  be applied to remote filesystems
   mounted outside of /usr or /var, without which  mountall(8)  would  not
   hold up the boot for these; ``nobootwait'' which can be applied to non-
   remote filesystems to explicitly instruct mountall(8) not  to  hold  up
   the boot for them; ``optional'' which causes the entry to be ignored if
   the filesystem type is not known  at  boot  time;  and  ``showthrough''
   which  permits  a mountpoint to be mounted before its parent mountpoint
   (this latter should be used carefully, as it can cause boot hangs).
```

specifically:

```
   ``optional'' which causes the entry to be ignored if
   the filesystem type is not known  at  boot  time
```

which I suspect could be combined with a filesystem type of `auto` and the `bootwait` option , in adition to `nofail` to cause the system to load the drive if present, and to fail and proceed if the drive is unavailable.

consider: [man mountall](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mountall.8.html) and [man fstab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/fstab.5.html)